# From many selected table rows to one div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

With selectable widget from jQuery I made a function to select rows in a table. Now i want that selected rows will form together a div tag (not many, just one big div) and to div tag to be able to add another functions like draggable and resizable, how to do this?

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gq3umkkb/)

```
jQuery("#wrapper>table>tbody").bind("mousedown", function(e) {
  e.metaKey = false;
}).selectable({
  filter: "td",
  stop: function( event, ui ) {
    jQuery( ".ui-selected").addClass('todiv');
  }
}); 

<div id="wrapper">
  <table>
    <col width="9%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">&nbsp;</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">&nbsp;</th>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">&nbsp;</th>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

table,th,tr,td { border: 1px solid black; }

.ui-selectable .ui-selected { background-color: #a6c9e2; }
.ui-selectable .ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }

.todiv { background-color: green; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just clone them and put in some container like this:

```
var selected = $('#wrapper .todiv');
$('#rowsContainer').empty().append(selected.clone());
```

But they will not look like rows in the table, you need to prepare separate style for them if you want that.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r6985fuo/)

Comment: Is a good idea, but after when the page needs to reload again will not have a selected area to clone, I opened another question to be more precise see here: [fix-height-of-an-absolute-positioned-div-tag-in-a-list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37221523/fix-height-of-an-absolute-positioned-div-tag-in-a-list).