# Fix height of an absolute positioned div tag in a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I positioned a div tag with absolute position in a grids list, so it is wrapped there by others div's. I would like to make a class that make the height of the absolute positioned div to flow till will meet another class to fix (or to close) the height of the absolute positioned div tag!

Or to find a solution to give a height to absolute positioned div from ex: row 1 to row 3 and so on? here is the code:

[*jsFiddle*](https://jsfiddle.net/p5hykd0x/)

```
<div id="wrap_day_kalendar">
    <div id="day_kalendar" class="ui-selectable">
        <div class="row"><span>Saturday, 14 May 2016</span></div>
        <div class="row dimgrey"><span>CEST +02:00</span></div>     

        <div class="row border-up">
            <div class="col-1 dimgrey text-right"><span class="">10 PM</span></div>
            <div class="col-11 cornsilk selectable ui-selectee"><span>&nbsp;</span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-1 dimgrey fix-border">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="col-11 border-up-dashed cornsilk selectable ui-selectee">
                <span>&nbsp;</span>
                <span class="newevent">New event</span>
                <span class="newevent">Second event</span>

            </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="row border-up">
            <div class="col-1 dimgrey text-right"><span class="">9 PM</span></div>
            <div class="col-11 cornsilk selectable ui-selectee"><span>&nbsp;</span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-1 dimgrey fix-border">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="col-11 border-up-dashed cornsilk selectable ui-selectee"><span>&nbsp;</span></div>
        </div>  
    <div class="row border-up">
        <div class="col-1 dimgrey text-right"><span class="">7 PM</span></div>
        <div class="col-11 cornsilk selectable ui-selectee"><span>&nbsp;</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-1 dimgrey fix-border">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-11 border-up-dashed cornsilk selectable ui-selectee"><span>&nbsp;</span></div>
    </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't get your point dude. you mean `@media query` ?

Comment: I need the div to flow on fixed grids but without knowing the height, from first row to third row for ex.

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/p5hykd0x/2/ sorry I can't get your point please elaborate more

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/p5hykd0x/3/ , i want the 'New event' div to be 3 rows height, without knowing the real height of the row ! (you see the white borders under, the dashed border also)

Comment: .newevent class has a auto height! I don't know how to give size, but not fix size, like exact pixels!!

Comment: try to use `@media(max-width:640px)` if a browser width reach to 640px the height you set will execute.

Comment: For now I am working not at 640px resolutions, or what for is this? for tablets smartphones et, this I will style at the very end dude!

Comment: can you draw what you want I will try to fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

With javascript/jQuery you can get the height of the parent div and of the x subsequent divs (if you iterate through the divs with .col-11 in this case) then you set the height of your div.

Here is a (stupid) example if you'd want to make all .newevent div 3 times the current cell height:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $('.newevent').each(function() {
           var parentHeight = parseInt($(this).parent().css('height'));
           $(this).css('height', 3 * parentHeight  + 'px');
      });
   })
```